# App Engine Python27 SDK - NDB Query.iter() QueryIterator returns "Deadlock waiting for, pending" error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

Since I am using NDB for my projects, on Python 2.7 SDK, I cannot use Query().iter() normally with Jinja2 templates.

My usual code follows this pattern:

```
mc_key = ...
instances = memcache.get('instances-%s' % mc_key)
if not instances:
    q_i = MyModel.query(...)
    instances = q_i.iter()
    if instances:
        memcache.set('instances-%s' % mc_key, instances)
```

And then in Jinja2:

```
{% for i in instances %}
    {{i.property1}}
{% endfor %}
```

This also happens when I call the QueryIterator object in the Python code. Adding to the previous Python code:

```
for i in instances:
    # Do something with i
```

I always get a "deadlock waiting for <future created by XXX, pending>" when I loop the iterator.

A working walkaround is:

```
q_i = MyModel.query()
instances = q_i.iter()
if instances:
    instances = list(instances)
```

Someone knows why that next() does not work as I expected? Some more elegant and/or efficient solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#iterators): `NDB uses Memcache as a cache service for "hot spots" in the data. If the application reads some entities often, NDB can read them quickly from cache.` In other words, the caching is automatic.

Also, the elegant way to get a list of entities is provided by the method `fetch()`

```
instances = MyModel.query().fetch(20)
```

For example, `instances` in this line is a list of 20 entities, and this list has already been written into the cache.

Comment: Ok, will use automatic MC from now on.
For the iter() vs fetch() issue, AFAIK DB run() and NDB iter() are the standard and recommended methods, and fetch() is only a wrap around run() and iter(). Is there a way to use iter() IteratorObject in a loop, whithout before making it a list or other iterator?